# Is Mathematica v10 on the Raspberry Pi licensed for classroom use?

Tags: licensing, raspberry-pi

Now that I have v10 running on my Raspberry Pi, I'm interested in what "personal and educational use" means.  As a Home user, I fully understand "personal"... but does "educational" mean that I'm free to donate a Raspberry Pi to my daughter's school and have Mathematica installed?  Or is it restricted to a single person's educational use?

And to all those who made this possible, my deepest gratitude!

Link to the license page:

http://wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: are you saying Mathematica version 10 was released for the platform you are using? Strange that WRI would release version 10 for one platform but not the others? Do you happen to know when windows version will be out? thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I assume that this is just a beta version.

Comment: The program installs into /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/ so I'm calling it v10.  The front end says Version Number 10.0.0.0

Comment: So, let me get this straight: it does not matter when (or where) you bought the Raspberry Pi, you can still install the free (for educational purpose) version of Mathematica via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine` ? Is that correct? (reference> http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5282 ).

Comment: Yes, all raspberry Pi's can install free mathematica, not sure about other ARM systems...

Comment: Excuse me a minute - er... Add to Basket... Proceed to Checkout... - you were saying? :-]  Amazing, Wolfram has outdone himself, this time. This will cause an avalanche of progress. If only I had Mathematica when I was 12 or 14 years old...

Comment: I think this is a question that only WRI can answer.  It's much better [to ask them directly](http://www.wolfram.com/company/contact/).  The people who answer here are just users, like you, and any answers you get might not be correct, might not stay correct a year from today; or people will be reluctant to answer for legal reasons.

Comment: I agree with @Szabolcs. This is a good question, but unfortunately we are not in a position at this site to answer it authoritatively. Therefore, I vote to close with the recommendation that you raise this directly with WRI. If it's closed before you receive an answer from them, when you do get it, please do vote to re-open so that you can post it here.